# Exported APK Not Working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apk, google-play

I've just published an app of mine to the Google Play Store and it seems that it keeps force closing and crashing on the users. 
I am not asking for a solution as to why, but i am curious.
On eclipse i have the Emulator and the target API of my app was Android-19 (it's 17 now because i'm changing that to see if it'll help). And while in eclipse and while running the emulator, with several devices (tablets, nexus one and such) , and the app works perfectly fine.

My friend has sent me a screenshot and the message that comes up once they try to open the app is "Unfortunately, Data Tool has stopped."

Any brainstorming ideas?

-Colt

**THIS ISSUE IS NOW FIXED!**

Comment: When it crashes, people have an option to report it.  Have they?  If so, what does the report say?

Comment: In your Google Play developer console, Crashes & ANRs, did you have a chance to view the crash logs (similar to LogCat)?

Comment: At the moment the Google Dev Console is showing 0 crashes. No idea why it's working perfectly fine on the emulator and yet force closes right away on a phone. And, Jeremy, so far no reports.

Comment: have you tried if the exported apk is working **before** uploading it to the play store? and i don't mean installing directly from eclipse. it's possible that this is a proguard (obfuscation tool) issue.

Comment: How do i test if it works **before** uploading it?

Comment: in Google Play developer console, there is a section called Crashes. Go and see all the details for your crash and solve, also you can post in here to get help. FYI, somebody has to report the crash for you to enable to see it. Good luck.

Comment: I've looked in "Crashes & ANRs" and there is no reported crashes. And from what I've seen it doesn't give the user an option to report the force close. It just says "Unfortunately, Data Tool has stopped."

Comment: i have experienced similar crash for my apk, though not on google play. Reason was Java 8 compatibility issue with maven android release plugin,After moving back to java 6 issue got resolved..

Comment: Not even sure how i'd move back to java 6 without having to rewrite my entire project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to locally test your app's release APK outside of Eclipse. It's written for Linux, but should be pretty close for other development hosts.

```
adb uninstall my.package.name; adb install -r my.package.apk && adb shell monkey -p my.package.name -s 0 1
```

This assumes the simplest case where you only have a single device connected. If you want a more versatile version that allows for easy switching between devices and/or versions, let me know and I'll add it.

Comment: Im using a macbook air and i copied and pasted this and hit enter and it said "-bash: adb: command not found"

Comment: And do you mean the terminal window on my computer or in the eclipse compiler? I apologize- I'm confused :3

Comment: On your desktop/laptop -- the machine that you use to run Eclipse. But not within Eclipse itself.

Comment: You need to add the platform-tools directory to your path or add it to each adb command. Depending on where you installed your Android SDK, you'd add the tools to your path with something like: export PATH="/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Documents/Android SDK/platform-tools/":$PATH

Answer (score 0):

Try building it without proguard first and test. If that works then its proguard configuration file issue.